# Imagemagick: how to resize 64pix -> 32 pix without edges

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm far from an expert with images and I'm new to imagemagick. I can't find the right options (this program is far to powerful for me at the moment :-)) **to convert a 64 pixel icon to 32 pixel with smooth edges**. It always give me rough edges. I tried with some of the -adaptive options but I'm stuck.

Is somebody over here more skilled in this kind of things? Startimage for example is this image: http://www.iconexperience.com/_img/v_collection_png/64x64/shadow/garbage.png What are the options to resize this in to a smooth icon.

(I know, we have the icon set too, so we could just take the 32 version, but we have over a hundred different icons in 64 pixel and we need sometimes them in 32 or 24 or 16 pixels. We're trying to automate the scalingproces to produce a sprite in our framework without developers need to worry with new icons. A 64 pixel version would be enough than.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get smooth-looking edges from the following:

```
convert garbage.png -resize 50% out.png
```

If I use -scale instead of -resize, then I get rough edges, which is to be expected, because -scale just uses a box filter.

```
convert garbage.png -scale 50% out.png   ## rough edges
```

You can experiment with different filters like this:

```
convert garbage.png -filter lanczos -resize 50% out.png
```

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#filter

Lanczos is the default filter in this case anyway, and the result looks pretty good to me.

Comment: Thanks! Via e-mail a friend told me another problem. We took the extension of the source image. Sometimes that was gif and that gave us terrible results. Now we always output to png. We tried the triangle filter but lanczos gives a much better result. Thanks for your input!!